# My javascript will not load my defined DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to coding and trying to implement some javascript into my site.

I have found this code online that does what I want it to do on jsfiddle and it works perfectly. When I copy the code exactly from jsfiddle to my coding program it wont load what I want it to load. I have included the HTML, CSS and JS to show how I am trying to get this working and how it should work.

Here is my javascript:

```
var startY = 70;

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        checkY();
    });

    function checkY() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > startY) {
            $('#skills-left').slideDown();
        }
    }
```

Code working on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rkerswell/jrpof73y/

When this code is transferred over to my program the code doesn't load the animation as described.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Make sure that you have loaded [jquery library](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery).

Comment: Did you put the js code in a script block (In JSFiddle it does it automatically for you)?

Comment: Can you include some of your html as well? Is the code in a `<script>` tag or a different file?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. here is the HTML from the header to the part that I am trying to apply this to. Hope this helps? Also I have included the `<script>` in the right place I think? Also here is some of the HTML? :) jsfiddle.net/rkerswell/jpx3vtb1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @tabz100

Make sure you wrap your javascript in this to ensure the code is run after the DOM elements are present. JSFiddle does this automatically.

```
$(function(){
   // Put code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the html code into the body tag when you copy it into the code editor and link jquery in the head tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies. here is the HTML from the header to the part that I am trying to apply this to. Hope this helps? Also I have included the `<script>` in the right place I think?

Comment: Here is the HTML as I cant seem to include it on here? :) http://jsfiddle.net/rkerswell/jpx3vtb1/